# get label value on uiswitch value change inside table view cell swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiswitch, swift4.2

i have a UITableviewcell with a label and switch.

[image]

cell label have dynamic values according to situation.

when i on/off switch. it just shows tag that which row switch state is changed. but i want to get exactly what is on label where switch is on/off.

```
 switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
 switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

//switch value change function
@objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){

        print("table row switch Changed \(sender.tag)")
       //looking for label text on this tag 
    }
```

is there any way to get cell label value when switch state changed inside tableview cell.

Comment: in which class you want label.

Comment: whenever switch state change in any cell. i want that cell's label text

Comment: in tableView right?

Comment: defiantly label and switch is in tableview...i want label value in switchChanged  function which is outside tableview functions

Comment: I have written answer please check.

Comment: Basically **never** get static values like a label (unlike a text field) from the cell (the view) get it from the data source array (the model).

Comment: well i got your point . this trick perfectly helped me in solving a certain problem thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare following closure variable in UItableViewCell

```
var returnBlock: ((String?)-> Void)?
```

and in switch method just call it with labelObj.text

```
    @objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){
             returnBlock?(labelObject.text)
        }
```

In TableViewController - CellForRowAtIndexPath method where you return cell before that write following code.

```
    cell.returnBlock = { labelText in 
               if let value = labelText {
                print(value)
               }
     }
```

There is many ways to do, but i think this is proper way.

For default UITableViewCell

```
  @objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){
        if let cellObj =  tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)) as? UITableViewCell {
     print(\(cellObj.labelObj.text ?? ""))
    }
   }
```

Comment: i am using default cell class UITableViewCell .. is it possible in it?

Comment: I suggest use your customCell instead of using default cell. If you want use default method then pas that tag to tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath method you will get cell and using that cell object you can access text of that label

Comment: Thank you .. let me try this

Comment: I have updated answer for default cell, check last code part.

Comment: working perfect in both default cell as well as in custom . Thank you so much